# Conditional format another sheet

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Hi guys I've looked at the other entries but can't seem to get it right.

I have two sheets, Sheet 1 is empty while Sheet 2 has text string entries.

I want to conditional format color fill the cells in Sheet 1 if Sheet 2 cell contains a particular string.

I have tried ='Sheet2!'A1="MB0" but it didn't work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

select  cell you want to format then go
1-Conditional formatting
2-New Rule
3-Select "Use formula to determine which cell to format"
Then put ='Sheet2!'A1="MB0" there